# How to test screen orientation with jest and testing-library/react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I wrote a test for a component in nextJs by testing-library/react and jestJs, and I checked "window.screen.orientation.type".
I got an error that "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')".
How can I resolve this? How can I mock it to work?

I tried to use jest.spyOn :

jest.spyOn(window.screen, "orientation", "get").mockReturnValue();

but I don't know how to pass return value as ScreenOrientation and mock type field.

I also tried this:

jest.spyOn(window.screen.orientation, "type", "get")
.mockReturnValue("portrait-primary");

and I got:

"Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given"

Comment: have checked with ternary expression with type.?

Comment: I just update my question about testing "type". How to use ternary expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found the solution for mocking orientation type and It's working now. I added this before render in test file:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.screen, "orientation", {
    value: { type: "portrait-primary" },
  });
```